# MTG Emrakul like cards

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What are good cards like [Emrakul, the Aeons Torn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Emrakul%2C%20the%20Aeons%20Torn) that are good for a green-black deck that revolves around [Deathrender](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deathrender)?

Comment: What do you mean by "like emrakul"? Do you just want all of the eldrazi creatures? All of the big ones? Do you just want a list of big expensive creatures?

Comment: [Here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx) is a link to Gatherer advanced search. [Here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&power=+%3E[10]) is a link to a search I performed for all creatures with power greater than 10. You could, for example, limit your search to only Green or Black cards.

Comment: http://magiccards.info also has some nice advanced search features. [This search](http://magiccards.info/query?q=pow%3E%3D10+c%21gbc&v=card&s=cname), for example, finds all creatures with power at least 10 that are Green, Black, or Colorless, as Rainbolt suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are cheating creatures onto the battlefield (i.e. not paying their mana cost), the creatures themselves need not be in green/black/colorless.  Try searching for creatures with [high converted mana costs](http://magiccards.info/query?q=cmc%3E%3D8%20t%3Acreature&v=card&s=cname).  They are the ones you are looking for to get the most value out of cards like deathrender.  Here are a few of my favorites:

[Worldspine Wurm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Worldspine%20Wurm), [Blightsteel Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blightsteel%20Colossus), [Iona, Shield of Emeria](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Iona%2C%20Shield%20of%20Emeria), [Blazing Archon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blazing%20Archon), [Platinum Emperion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Emperion), [Avacyn, Angel of Hope](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Avacyn%2C%20Angel%20of%20Hope)